# Can protocol buffers be used to implement a 3rd party protocol

Tags: serialization, protocol-buffers

Is it possible to use google protocol buffers as the serialisation mechanism when only one end of the comms channel is using it?

ie given a client that needs to speak to some 3rd party server or hardware that communicates in some defined message byte structure.

is it possible to specify the exact byte structure to expect using the protobuf IDL? Or does protobuf use it's own byte packing format therefore both ends must speak using protobuf protocol?

If not protobuf is there some library that would achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Protocol buffers has a very rigid layout, that cannot be changed, and is unlikely to match the one you are using *unless* it is secretly using protocol buffers and just not advertising that fact. The encoding is [documented here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding).

As for alternatives; that would depend hugely on what platform / language / framework you are using. It would not be unusual to find you have to write your own tools for talking the required protocol.

Comment: ok thanks. does seem like it should be feasable to specify the format enough for some library to do this kind of thing. eg. describe a byte layout, endianess etc in idl from which pack/unpack routines are created or generated..